# Progress while recording audio

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to make a progress bar , that will react while i will record sound. I mean while record is ON and there is a sound my progress bar have to move. I dont know how should i call it but it is often using in audio players to show that music is playing. I hope you know what i mean.

I am recording sound with this code:

```
                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);             
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                recorder.setOutputFile(outputfile);
```

Comment: I guess what you need is a `SeekBar`.

Comment: or progressbar i dont know which one will be better to do this.

Comment: SeekBar has a limit if you are recording a audio than what will be the limit of your seekbar and how long will it record

Answer (score 5):

Use [getMaxAmplitude()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude()).

Call the method multiple times with a delay and you will get what you need.

Here's an implementation using `RxJava`:

```
mTimerSubscription = Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(aLong -> {
            // evey 100 milliseconds this method is called
            int amplitude = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            LogWrapper.d(TAG, "amplitude: " + amplitude + " rms " + (int) Math.sqrt(amplitude));
            mSoundProgressBar.setProgress((int) Math.sqrt(amplitude));
        });
```

You can very well do it using [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).

Answer (score 2):

```
class Recording extends Activity
{

Timer timer = new Timer();
ProgressBar pb;
Button startRecording;
Button stop;
MediaRecorder recorder;
int MAX_DURATION=60000;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setContentView(R.layout.recording)
            pb          =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            startRecording  =(Button)findViewById(R.id.startRecording);
            stop        =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);             
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(outputfile);


            recorder.setMaxDuration(MAX_DURATION); //supposing u want to give maximum length of 60 seconds
            pb.setMax(MAX_DURATION); //supposing u want to give maximum length of 60 seconds
            pb.setProgress(0);
            startProgress();

            startRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        stopped=false;
                        recorder.start();

                    }
                });

             stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            stopped=true;
                            pb.setProgress(0); // if u want to reset
                            recorder.stop();


                    }
                });
    }


void startProgress()
{
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(!stopped)  // call ui only when  the progress is not stopped
                        {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try 
                                    {

                                            pb.setProgress(pb.getProgress()+1000);

                                    } catch (Exception e) {}



                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }



            }, 1, 1000);


}

}
```

Hope it helps and give u an idea :)